# Compute euclidean distance, incrementally assign x, y to prime numbers in range loop with R

Tags: r, primes, euclidean-distance

### Purpose

For range loop on prime numbers, assigning x, y, and calculate distance between points and from origin of two dimension chart

### Problem

Compute euclidean distance from within for range loop, moves has prime numbers, running incrementally, use j to assign moves[j] to x, then on every other range loop, assign the next j moves[j+1] to y. The sequence should be x=2  y=3  x=5  y=7 x=11 y=13 x=17 y=19 x=23 y=29 x=31 y=37...x=89 y=97. Then each pair of x,y should compute the euclidean distance.

### Code

```
euclidean <- function(x, y) sqrt(sum((x - y)^2))

x = 0
y = 0
s = (NULL)
for (j in range(length(moves)-1)) {
  if ((j %% 2) == 0) {
    x <- moves[j]
  } else {
    y <- moves[j+1]
  }
  append(s, euclidean(x,y))
  print(euclidean(x,y)) # just a test!
  j=+1
}
output:
[1] 86
[1] 86
```

### Data for prime numbers

```
moves
 2  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Comment: `range` returns only two values and the loop control becomes `j in c(1, 96)`.

Comment: yes, so j should walk from 1 to 96 inside the loop, but my assignments appear to skip until the ending numbers in moves vector

Comment: for (j in moves) {}. Looks like I need to fix the for on j to catch each 'moves'

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way.
Create a vector of the even indices to `moves`. Even because the calculations come in pairs, effectively discarding the last, 25th element of `moves` since there is no following `y`. Then, call `euclidean` on each pair in a `sapply` loop, a one-liner will do it.

```r
# data
moves <- scan(text = "
2  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
")
moves
#>  [1]  2  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97


euclidean <- function(x, y) sqrt(sum((x - y)^2))

inx <- seq_along(moves)[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
inx
#>  [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24

sapply(inx, \(i) euclidean(moves[i - 1L], moves[i]))
#>  [1] 1 2 2 2 6 6 2 6 2 4 6 6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>